# Asignación de intervalos de tiempos

Tags: sql-server, date, setinterval

Hice el siguiente ejemplo que aplicaria para la lógica de algo mayor, la cual tiene como objetivo asignar el intervalo de tiempo a un intervalo de media hora:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Data')       IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Data      END
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Interval')   IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Interval  END

SET DATEFIRST 1;

CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [empleado_id]   VARCHAR(5),
    [date]          DATE,
    [time_start]    TIME(0),
    [time_end]      TIME(0),
    [excepcion]     VARCHAR(15),
    [excep_start]   TIME(0),
    [excep_end]     TIME(0)
)
CREATE TABLE #Interval(
    [time]          TIME(0)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','break','12:30:00','12:45:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','lunch','15:00:00','16:00:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','break','17:15:00','17:30:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-07','07:00:00','11:00:00','break','09:00:00','09:15:00'),
       ('0022','2020-07-08','12:00:00','20:00:00','lunch','15:00:00','16:00:00')

INSERT INTO #Interval
VALUES ('07:00'),('07:30'),('08:00'),('08:30'),('09:00'),('09:30'),('10:00'),('10:30'),
       ('11:00'),('11:30'),('12:00'),('12:30'),('13:00'),('13:30'),('14:00'),('14:30'),
       ('15:00'),('15:30'),('16:00'),('16:30'),('17:00'),('17:30'),('18:00'),('18:30'),
       ('19:00'),('19:30'),('20:00'),('20:30')

SELECT *
FROM #Data
ORDER BY 1

--  SELECT * FROM #Interval ORDER BY 1
```

Esto genera lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se maneja de la siguiente forma:
La data es para horario de salidas programadas en el sistema, se tiene a un empleado con su registro por dia y un horario especifico el cual se ve en `time_start` y `time_end`, la excepción (o LOG de salida al sistema) se marca a través de una excepción en especifico con nombre en `excepcion` y marca el nombre de su salida y el tiempo que debe de salir de acuerdo a la programación en `excep_start` y `excep_end`.

Y bien, llevo rato quebrándome la cabeza para que, en base a una escala de intervalo (como la de la tabla `#Interval`) se asocie con un 1 si el empleado (ejemplo 0011) estuvo durante su intervalo de tiempo (8 horas que va desde las 11am a 7 pm) mostrando algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí muestra el ejemplo del empleado 0011 donde cumple con sus dos tiempos de break (ya que si esta 15 minutos de su intervalo de 12:30 y 17:00 hrs) pero su excepción de 1 hora de break le cuesta que *no* este en dos intervalos (15:00 y 15:30 hrs).

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho, no pongo las pruebas debido a lo extenso e inútil que quedaría (realmente).

**Editado:** abra distintas excepciones que puedan sumar tiempo y estas afectarían a la forma de calculo, ejemplo sencillo: dos break seguidos de 15 min sumarian la media hr que esta puede afectar si es en un horario de intervalo completo.

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es eliminar la tabla de tiempos y reconvertirla en una función tipo tabla.

```
Create function dbo.tiempos (@timeIni time(0), @timeEnd time(0))
Returns table
return
Select * from 
(VALUES ('07:00'),('07:30'),('08:00'),('08:30'),('09:00'),('09:30'),('10:00'),('10:30'),
       ('11:00'),('11:30'),('12:00'),('12:30'),('13:00'),('13:30'),('14:00'),('14:30'),
       ('15:00'),('15:30'),('16:00'),('16:30'),('17:00'),('17:30'),('18:00'),('18:30'),
       ('19:00'),('19:30'),('20:00'),('20:30')) tbl (tiempo)
Where tbl.tiempo between @timeIni and @timeEnd
```

Con la misma, puedes utilizar una tabla de expresión común para recoger los datos del empleado, y numerar las filas. De la primera puedes obtener los datos, de "digamos" entrada y salida.

Con estos mezclas los mismos con la función de tiempos y si alguna fila de las numeradas contiene una excepción de tipo lunch, recoges esto en un case.

A la salida de la tabla de expresión común obtienes los resultados agrupados, donde la columna estuvo, recoge las excepciones.

Esto te permite, marcar como excepciones para la columna estuvo, más causísticas.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Data')       IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Data      END

SET DATEFIRST 1;

CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [empleado_id]   VARCHAR(5),
    [date]          DATE,
    [time_start]    TIME(0),
    [time_end]      TIME(0),
    [excepcion]     VARCHAR(15),
    [excep_start]   TIME(0),
    [excep_end]     TIME(0)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','break','12:30:00','12:45:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','lunch','15:00:00','16:00:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-06','11:00:00','19:00:00','break','17:15:00','17:30:00'),
       ('0011','2020-07-07','07:00:00','11:00:00','break','09:00:00','09:15:00'),
       ('0022','2020-07-08','12:00:00','20:00:00','lunch','15:00:00','16:00:00');

With datos
     as (SELECT *
              , row_number() over(--partition by empleado_id
                order by date) as row
                FROM #Data AS d
                where d.empleado_id = '0011' and d.date = '20200706'),
     tiempos
     as (Select fn.tiempo
              , d.date
              , d.empleado_id as empleado
              , case
                     when d.row > 1 and d.excepcion = 'lunch' 
                     and fn.tiempo >= d.excep_start and fn.tiempo < d.excep_end then 0
                     else 1
                end as estuvo
                from datos AS d
                          CROSS APPLY dbo.tiempos
                     ( d.time_start, d.time_end ) AS fn)
     select t.tiempo
          , t.date
          , t.empleado
          , min(t.estuvo) as estuvo
            from tiempos AS t
            group by t.tiempo
                   , t.date
                   , t.empleado;
```

[image: Resultado]

[Cross apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/?s=cross%20apply)

[Row number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: De antemano gracias por tu aportación, eh estado trabajando a lo largo del dia en algunos detalles que surgieron... Crees que me puedas apoyar solo con un caso curioso? Eje, dos breaks seguidos de 15 min durante un intervalo debería ser contado para 0 en [estuvo] eso solo si es de 12:00 a 12:30 como ejemplo y como total de tiempo (30 min)  ya que si fuera 12:15 a 12:45 pues en logica esta (aunque sea solo 15 min de cada intervalo)

Comment: Si planteas ese tipo de excepciones entre horarios que no encajan en los intervalos, entonces no puedes utilizar una tabla ni función para eso. Deberías utilizar la función sum para obtener los intervalos de tiempo y con esos intervalos aplicar tu lógica de negocio. Por ej.select
  d.excepcion,
    ((SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, d.excep_start, d.excep_end)) % 86400) % (3600)) / 60 AS minutos
    ,((SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, d.excep_start, d.excep_end)) % 86400) / (3600))  AS horas
 from datos d 
 group by d.excepcion